# {update}Discord bot send only msgs but didnt send pictures

Tags: discord.js

My discord bot is stucking on a loop of deleting and sending messages,

My code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.channel.id === 'channel id') {
    msg.delete();
    msg.channel.send(msg.content);
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ignore the messages sent by bots.

---

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false

    // your code goes here
});
```

---

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;
    const Attachments = [];
    
    if (message.attachments) {
        message.attachments.forEach(attachment => Attachments.push(new discord.MessageAttachment(attachment.url)));
    };

    message.channel.send(message.content || "", Attachments).then(message.delete());
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_AUTH_TOKEN);
```

Comment: throw err;


`const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.author.bot) return false 
   (msg.channel.id === '734280312976310356') 
    msg.delete();
    msg.channel.send(msg.content);
  
});

client.login('token');  `
`

Comment: @ZeusUchiha I've updated my answer and fixed your code.

Comment: im still getting this throw rr; error i dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? Also, which version of Discord JS are you using?

Comment: it works perfect expect the fact i cant send pictures i solve the error thing it was my bad

Comment: @ZeusUchiha I've updated my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: @ZeusUchiha congrats on getting it working, remember to mark the answer as correct :)